# Cannot find module in vite-plugin-federation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, micro-frontend, vite-plugin-development

I have 2 projects, a host app and a remote app. In the remote one I create a Logo component that displays an svg element. I export this component and try to use it in the Header component on the host application, but there I get the error "Cannot find module 'remoteApp/Logo' or its corresponding type declarations". But when I try to import it into App.tsx, there is no error.
My vite config in host:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        federation({
            name: "app",
            remotes: {
                remoteApp: "http://localhost:5001/assets/remoteEntry.js",
            },
            shared: ["react", "react-dom"],
        }),
    ],
    
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: "esnext",
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
});
```

In remote app:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        react(),
        federation({
            name: "remote_app",
            filename: "remoteEntry.js",
            exposes: {
                "./Button": "./src/components/Button/Button.tsx",
                "./store": "./src/store.js",
                "./Logo": "./src/components/Logo/Logo.tsx",
            },
            shared: ["react", "react-dom", "jotai"],
        }),
    ],
    build: {
        modulePreload: false,
        target: "esnext",
        minify: false,
        cssCodeSplit: false,
    },
});
```

I don't know what I did wrong and I'm trying to change the src for the import but it doesn't work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot find module in vite-plugin-federation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77287472/cannot-find-module-in-vite-plugin-federation)

Comment: @PooriaSet oh, this is also my question, I don't know why, but for some reason it was created twice, but there is also no answer, I'll delete it now.

Comment: I really can't figure out what the problem is, and I'm not quite sure how to google it

Comment: is there any solution? I am getting same error